# Edge progressive app: how to remove the newly added address bar

Tags: microsoft-edge, progressive-web-app

We had a progressive web app for a textual game client and we are using it precisely because it offered more vertical space when installed as an app.

Recently Edge did some change where it added a bar on top that interferes with the vertical space of the app.

Is there a way to remove it?

This is a screenshot of what needs to be removed:
[image]

Comment: Is this the App you are using causing the issue?  I have the newest version of Edge running on a couple of Windows 11 Pro machines and the address bar is just one line in all cases.

Comment: OP clearly does not want any address bar all, be it one or two lines.

Comment: If you do not want any address bar (not even one):  (a) there was no Edge change with respect to this; and (b) I do not think you can do what you wish with Edge and so you may need a special purpose browser.

Comment: I simply want it as it was before. Without the highlighted area in the screenshot.